# Why is the elif statement invalid in this code?

Tags: python

```
a = float(input("Insert a floating point number:"))
n = int(input("Insert an integer number >= 0 :"))
accum = 1
count = 1

while n >= count and n >= 0: 
  accum = accum * a
  count += 1
elif n < 0:
    print("Integer value is less than 0")
if n >=0 and n < count:
  print(accum)
```

I need to create a code which asks the user for a floating point number 'a' then an integer to use as the power of 'a' which is 'n'. I need to use a while loop and it must be valid for n>=0 only. If I don't have the elif statement then the code runs normally.

Comment: use `if` instead of `elif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While technically you can put `n >= 0` in the condition of the `while` loop to skip the loop if `n < 0`, it doesn't make sense to do so, because you never modify the value of `n` *in* the loop. It would be clearer to put the entire loop in the body of another `if` statement (which, incidentally, is the one which your `elif`—or `else`, as we'll see—would naturally belong to.)

```
a = float(input("Insert a floating point number:"))
n = int(input("Insert an integer number >= 0 :"))
accum = 1
count = 1

if n >= 0:
    while n >= count: 
        accum = accum * a
        count += 1

    # We already know n >= 0, and the only way
    # for the loop to exit is for n < count to be
    # true, so no additional testing needed before
    # we call print here.
    print(accum)
else:  # If n >= 0 is not true, n < 0 *must* be true
    print("Integer value is less than 0")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid because you firstly need to add an `if` statement and then follow it with an `elif`.

```
if n < 0:
    print("Integer value is less than 0")
elif n >=0 and n < count:
  print(accum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the elif and if statement position

```
while n >= count and n >= 0: 
  accum = accum * a
  count += 1
if n >=0 and n < count:
      print(accum)
elif n < 0:
    print("Integer value is less than 0")
```

Else if always comes after if